# Convert CFStringRef to QString

Tags: macos, qt, cfstring

cross platform c++ header file. separate c++ file for each platform: windows, linux, mac. Deals with platform specific implementation of enumerating windows.

on the mac side: I have a CFStringRef populated. the header file defines a QString object. I need to pass the contents of the CFStringRef to the QString.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the static function used internally by Qt (from src/corelib/kernel/qcore_mac.cpp):

```
QString QCFString::toQString(CFStringRef str)
{
    if (!str)
        return QString();

    CFIndex length = CFStringGetLength(str);
    if (length == 0)
        return QString();

    QString string(length, Qt::Uninitialized);
    CFStringGetCharacters(str, CFRangeMake(0, length), reinterpret_cast<UniChar *> 
        (const_cast<QChar *>(string.unicode())));
    return string;
}
```

**Update (2020):** nowadays use [QString::fromCFString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromCFString) as @ehopperdietzel suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fromCFString()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromCFString) method included in the [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) class:

```
CFStringRef str = CFSTR("Hello World!");
QString convertedStr = QString::fromCFString(str);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Calos changes made ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but I would do something like this:

```
QVector<UniChar> uniChars(CFStringGetLength(cfStr));
CFStringGetCharacters(cfStr, CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(cfStr), uniChars.data());
QString qString = QString::fromUtf16(uniChars.data(), uniChars.size());
```

To avoid allocation of the UniChar buffer, you can try `CFStringGetCharactersPtr()` first and use the buffer one as a fall back.